# Сборка библиотеки для tdlib на maco

Tags: c, macos, tdlib

На 73% выпададает ошибка `ld: library not found for -lws2_32`

Полный лог через -v

```
cd /Users/david/td/build/td/generate &&Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -std=c++14 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -Wall -Wextra -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wsign-compare -Wno-tautological-compare -Wpointer-arith -Wvla -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wno-unused-parameter -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion -Wc++14-compat-pedantic -Wdeprecated -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -Qunused-arguments -Wodr -O3 -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/generate_json.dir/generate_json.cpp.o CMakeFiles/generate_json.dir/tl_json_converter.cpp.o -o generate_json ../../tdtl/libtdtl.a ../../tdutils/libtdutils.a /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd -lws2_32 -lMswsock -lCrypt32 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd -lws2_32 -lMswsock -lCrypt32
```

Comment: ws2_32 - это библиотека сокетов для Windows. На маке такого нет (по крайней мере такого нет на Linux)

Comment: Я тоже нарыл такую инфу что это либа для винды.  Но не пойму как тогда собирать мне на маке. Через оф документацию телеги сборка идет с теми же командами что я ввожу.

Comment: (ох и вопросец - сразу два красных флага - макос и телеграм. это ж надо так придумать:) )   Так как там похоже cmake, нужно запускать генерацию проекта. Показывайте как собираете

Comment: По инструкции https://tdlib.github.io/td/build.html?language=Go

Comment: посмотрел в репозитории в файл CMakeLists.txt, там будет подключатся ws2_32 только для винды. Либо генерация не проходила (скопировали сорцы вручную с винды), либо у вас сломанная макось

Comment: Странно. Ладно буду еще ковырять , спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась у них в master ветке под HEAD. Нужно было просто качать опредленный тег, на момент когда я это делал был тег 1.6. Всем Спасибо